# Count the number of hyphens in a name using R

Tags: r

I have a data set with a certain amount of names. How can I count the number of names with at least one hyphen using R?

Comment: Welcome Navid. It would help if you read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  In general, people asking questions here include some code that they tried and also so simple example data for people to use in answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `grepl`

```
sum(grepl('-', df$Name))
```

Or with `grep`

```
length(grep('-', df$Name))
```

Using a reproducble example,

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c('name1-name2', 'name1name2', 
                          'name1-name2-name3', 'name2name3'))

sum(grepl('-', df$Name))
#[1] 2

length(grep('-', df$Name))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_count` to get the number of hyphens and then count by creating a logical vector and get the `sum`

```
library(stringr)
sum(str_count(v1, "-") > 0)
```